# Use a different field for axis tick values

Tags: d3.js

I've created a row chart with D3 and create my y-axis like so:

```
  var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.name }))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, data.length * barHeight], 0.05);

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient('left');
```

My source data is an array of the following objects:

```
id: 1,
name: "Test" // y-axis value
score: 10 // x-axis value
```

This worked fine until I had two objects with the same name. I therefore changed my y-scale to use the `id` field instead since this is always unique.

Of course doing so means I now get the `id` as my y-axis tick values rather than the name. So how can I use a different value in my source data as the tick value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.tickFormat()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat):

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yScale)
  .orient('left')
  .tickFormat(function(d, i) { return data[i].name; });
```

Unfortunately it's not perfectly straightforward as only the label is passed into the function, so you have to get the index and use that to index in the data.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k3a7k/).

Comment: When I try that `d` is the id parameter, not the entire object.

Comment: My apologies, wasn't quite as easy as I thought. Fixed.